# Habilitar un input con un checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html5

me ayudan por favor con este problema quiero que cuando seleccione el `checkbox` se active el `input`, lo quiero hacer con `readonly` por que con `disabled` no me guarda en la `BD` , con `disabled` si funciona pero con `readonly` no.

```js
   function comprobar(obj)
{   
    if (obj.checked)
      document.getElementById('boton').readOnly = false;
        
    else
      document.getElementById('boton').readOnly = true;
        
}
```

```html
<input name="chec" type="checkbox" id="chec" onChange="comprobar(this);"/>
    <label for="chec">Activar</label>
 
    <input name="text" id="boton" readonly />
```

Comment: Al ejecutar tu código en el snippet funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo aca te paso el codigo para lograr eso que quieres con JavaScript

```js
   function comprobar(obj)
{   
    if (obj.checked){
      
document.getElementById('boton').style.display = "";
   } else{
      
document.getElementById('boton').style.display = "none";
   }     
}
```

```html
<input name="chec" type="checkbox" id="chec" onChange="comprobar(this);"/>
    <label for="chec">Activar</label>
 
    <input name="text" id="boton" readonly style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function comprobar()
{   
    if (document.getElementById("chec").checked)
      document.getElementById('boton').readOnly = false;
        
    else
      document.getElementById('boton').readOnly = true;
        
}
```

```html
<input name="chec" type="checkbox" id="chec" onchange="comprobar();"/>
    <label for="chec">Activar</label>
 
    <input name="text" id="boton" readonly />
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo te adjunto mi solución:

```js
function comprobar()
{
  document.getElementById('boton').readOnly = !document.getElementById("chec").checked;
}
```

```html
<input name="chec" type="checkbox" id="chec" onchange="comprobar();"/>
<label for="chec">Activar</label>
<input name="text" id="boton" readonly="true" />
```